# How to calculate the value of checked box?

Tags: php, jquery, checkbox

I have table which contain following data structure:

| ID | payroll_cat_name | payroll_cat_code | category_type | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Provident Fund | PF | dedution | 1000 |
| 2 | Basic Pay | BC | earning | 35000 |
| 3 | Travelling | TA | earning | 6500 |
| 4 | Home Allowance | HM | earning | 12000 |
| 5 | Tax | TX | dedution | 500 |

I am fetching this all data with this code below:

```
<?php
include "../db.php";
$select_payroll_category = "SELECT * from payroll_category";
$employee_payroll_result = mysqli_query($con,$select_payroll_category);
?>
<table>
    <thead style="color: #222426;">
        <tr>
            <th>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input checkAll">
                    <label class="form-check-label">ID</label>
                </div>
            </th>
            <th>Category name</th>
            <th>Category code</th>
            <th>Category Type</th>
            <th>Category Amount</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($employee_payroll_result)) {
            echo "<tr style='color:#222426;'>
                    <td>
                    <div class='form-check'>
                    <input type='checkbox' name='payroll_group' value=".$row["amount"]."class='form-check-input'>
                    <label class='form-check-label' style='color:#fff;'>".$row["payroll_cat_id"]."</label>
                    </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>".$row["payroll_cat_name"]."</td>
                    <td>".$row["payroll_cat_code"]."</td>
                    <td>".$row["category_type"]."</td>
                    <td>".$row["amount"]."</td>
                    
                  </tr>";
                    }
                    ?>
                        
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <button id="button">save</button>
                <p id="result"></p>
```

Now On `button`click I want to calculate the amount based on category_type,

If the category is `earning` then it will add the amount ,

And if the category is `dedution` then it will subtract the amount,

Using jquery, I want to perform this

Following is my jquery code which I have tried,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#button").click(function(){
            var favorite = [];
            $.each($("input[name='payroll_group']:checked"), function(){
                favorite.push($(this).val());
            });
            var total = 
            console.log("My favourite sports are: " + favorite);
            $('#result').html(favorite);
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

By using this code I m getting `1000,35000,6500` the value of amount Which I have ticked in checkbox

Comment: Is the problem that you have the correct numbers, and now you don't know what to do with them as you have lost the `earning` / `deduction` information?

Comment: Yes I got the numbers(amount) and Now I have to calculate the amount Which I have ticked in checkbox according to its type (earning / deduction) if it is `earning` it will add the amount, and if it is `deduction ` it will subtract the amount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```html
<body>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><div><input type="checkbox"></div></td>
                <td>...</td>
                <td>...</td>
                <td>deducing</td>
                <td>1000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div><input type="checkbox"></div></td>
                <td>...</td>
                <td>...</td>
                <td>earning</td>
                <td>6000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div><input type="checkbox"></div></td>
                <td>...</td>
                <td>...</td>
                <td>earning</td>
                <td>3000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div><input type="checkbox"></div></td>
                <td>...</td>
                <td>...</td>
                <td>earning</td>
                <td>1200</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div><input type="checkbox"></div></td>
                <td>...</td>
                <td>...</td>
                <td>deducing</td>
                <td>1000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="button" id="button">Yo</button>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#button").click(function() {
                let total = 0;
                $("tbody:first tr").each(function() {
                    if ($(this).children("td").first().children("div").children("input").is(":checked")) {
                        if ("deducing" == $(this).children("td").eq(3).text()) total = total - parseInt($(this).children("td").eq(4).text());
                        else if ("earning" == $(this).children("td").eq(3).text()) total = total + parseInt($(this).children("td").eq(4).text());
                    }
                });
                alert(total);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply i have tried this code but still I am facing this error                                         ```Uncaught TypeError: $(...).find(...)[3].text is not a function
    at HTMLTableRowElement.<anonymous> (new.php:123)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at w.fn.init.each (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (new.php:122)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at HTMLButtonElement.y.handle (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)```

Comment: I have replaced `[3]` with `eq(3)` then it is showing error ``` Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier```

Comment: I have replaced `[3]` with `eq(3)` then it is showing error ``` Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier```

Comment: Ok but what i want is it should calculate only that amount which i have selected    eg:```<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='payroll_group' value="1000" class='form-check-input'></td>
          <td>deducing</td>
          <td>1000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type='checkbox' name='payroll_group' value="6000" class='form-check-input'></td>
                <td>earning</td>
                <td>6000</td>
            </tr>```

Comment: So if there is deduction it will subtract and if `earning it will add from my selected option

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226279/discussion-between-deepak-pal-and-dm-tr).

Answer (score 0):

If [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65390422/how-to-calculate-the-value-of-checked-box#comment115607516_65390422) is correct, and the issue here is that you have the correct amounts, but have lost the "meta information" of whether to add or subtract to the total, then I think the simplest solution would be to do the following:

Firstly change the value of the checkbox so that it reflects the action to take - ie if it is `deduction` then make the value negative. So your `input` would be:

```php
<input type='checkbox' name='payroll_group' value=" . ($row['category_type'] === 'deduction' ? $row["amount"] * -1 : $row["amount"]) . "class='form-check-input'>
```

Where `($row['category_type'] === 'deduction' ? $row["amount"] * -1 : $row["amount"])` will check if the `category_type` is `deduction` then multiply `amount` by `-1` otherwise keep the current `amount` value. Note the surrounding parenthesis are necessary.

Then in your current js, you should end up with `[-1000,35000,6500]` in your current example. You can then do a simple loop to go through the array and add to a total, or you could use something like [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
var totalAmount = favorite.reduce(
    function (total, amount) {
        return parseInt(total) + parseInt(amount)
    },
    0 // The initial value to start with
)
```